# my image doesn't fit the entire height of its container

Tags: html, css, image, height, width

I have an image inside of my div element and I want my image to fit the entire height of its container but this doesn't happen. my image is square. I have to mention that I don't care about the aspect ratio.
[this is my code](https://jsfiddle.net/yunes_frontend/49ozn6v5/24/)

I tried object-fit property but it didn't help.

```css
.container {
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <img src="https://cdn140.picsart.com/39063465592866053138.webp?type=webp" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: `img { display: block }` will do the trick. An image is default `display: inline` causing a gap below the element. Just a thing to remember....

Comment: but the div tag should expand exactly as high as the image. why its height is more than the image's height ?

Comment: Rene just explained why there's a gap under the image. It's to leave room for any descenders of text that might sit next to the image. An alternative to `display: block` on the image is `vertical-align: bottom`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `height` property of the container to get your achieved result. This will give the image an idea of what `100% height` mean.

```css
.container {
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  /* added this. You can adjust this as per your requirement */
  background-color: red;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <img src="https://cdn140.picsart.com/39063465592866053138.webp?type=webp" alt="">
</div>
```

If you do not want to manually provide a specific height, another thing you can do is to use `flex` on container. Something like:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <img src="https://cdn140.picsart.com/39063465592866053138.webp?type=webp" alt="">
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by **@ralph.m** and **@Rene van der Lende**, you can use **`display: block`** or **`vertical-align: bottom`** on image which would also do the work for you with least of efforts.

Comment: This is not a good solution, and quite unnecessary. It's just the default inline alignment of the image that's at issue. No need to mess around with fixed heights.

Comment: It's overkill for this particular issue. Images are `display: inline` by default, meaning that they will align with the baseline of any text sitting beside them (like words of text). If you don't want that behavior, it's best just to use `vertical-align: bottom` on the image, or set the image to `display: block` or similar. It's not really fair to put the onus on the container to fix an issue with the image itself!